# Text file data to an associative array in PHP and search data

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm a beginner in PHP. I have a text file like this:

```
Name-Id-Number
Abid-01-80
Sakib-02-76
```

I can take the data as an array but unable to take it as an associative array. I want to do the following things:

- Take the data as an associative array in PHP.
- Search Number using ID.
- Find out the total of Numbers

Comment: please, give ur required ans and your so far completed ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I understand what you want, and it's fairly simple.  First you need to read the file into a php array.  That can be done with something like this:

`$filedata = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);`

Now build your desired array using a foreach() loop, explode and standard array assignment.  Your search requirement is unclear, but in this example, I make the associated array element into an array that is also an associative array with keys for 'id' and 'num'.

As you create the new array, you can compute your sum, as demonstrated.

```
<?php

$filedata = array('Abid-01-80', 'Sakib-02-76');

$lineArray = array();
$numTotal = 0;

foreach ($filedata as $line) {
    $values = explode('-', $line);
    $numTotal += $values[2];
    $lineArray[$values[0]] = array('id' => $values[1], 'num' => $values[2]);
}

echo "Total: $numTotal\n\n";
var_dump($lineArray);
```

You can [see this code demonstrated here](https://3v4l.org/WVcG8)

***Updated response:***

Keep in mind that notices are not errors.  They are notifiying you that your code could be cleaner, but are typically suppressed in production.

The undefined variable notices are coming because you are using:

`$var += $var` without having initialized $var previously. Note that you were inconsistent in this practice.  For example you initialized $numTotal, so you didn't get a notice when you used the same approach to increment it.

Simply add just below `$numTotal = 0`:

```
$count = 0;
$countEighty = 0;
```

Your other notices are occurring most likely due to a blank line or string in your input that does not follow the pattern expected.  When explode is executed it is not returning an array with 3 elements, so when you try and reference `$values = explode('-', $line);` you need to make sure that $line is not an empty string before you process it.  You could also add a sanity check like:

`enter code here`if (count($values) === 3) { // It's ok to process

Comment: I'm sorry fr my unclear statement. I'm new here so I think I need some time to get used to.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had an extra line at the end of the text file. I have removed it and now it's working fine.